# how to clone while drag and hide cloned item jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

How to hide dragged item while cloning it

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ 
    helper: "clone"
});
```

**I want to hide cloned item while dragging**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS class for the helper is `ui-draggable-helper`

You can use CSS to hide it:

```
.ui-draggable-helper
{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not work with "ui-draggable-helper" class , i search for it's class name and by firebug and i find it's name "ui-draggable-dragging" and then working :)